# Write a huge array list (200000 entries) to a text file java

Tags: java, list, file, arraylist

I need to write all the entries of an arrayList of 200000 entries to a text file. I have persisted it but I want a editable simple text file rather than object dump. I have used number of methods but for some reason it only writes around 1/4 of the list. I have used FileWriter, PrintStream, FileUtils. Everything cuts it off t around 1/4. Can anybody please tell me if there is an error in my implementation or understanding since its a huge list and I am not getting any exception and lastly if anybody can please provide me any solution!  I apologize for earlier way of asking without code. Here are the codes I have tried till now:

```
List<String> readList;

Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("absolute/path/demoTest.txt"), "utf-8"));

        for (String entry : readList) {

            writer.write(entry);
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        writer.close();
```

Next:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("absolute/path/demoTest.txt"); 
for (String entry : readList) {

            writer.write(entry);
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        writer.close();
```

Next:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("absolute/path/demoTest.txt"));
```

Lastly:

```
FileUtils.writeLines(new File("absolute/path/demoTest.txt"), readList);
```

So like I said there are 200000 entries, but I only get 1/4 of the total entries on the output text file. If the array is like:
    1
    2
    3
    ...
   200000
The output file shows something like:
1
2
3
...
50000

Comment: "_If there is an error in my implementation_" Where is it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Make sure you close the output file.

Comment: Sorry about the earlier way of asking the question. I included some codes and the difference in structure of the actual array and output array. Thanks for taking time on this.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes I have made sure I have closed it everytime. Thanks

Comment: One more thing, all of the methods cut me off exactly at the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<String> lines = // ...
Files.write(Paths.get("output.txt"), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Then your list actually contains less than you think

Comment: no I did checked the size of the array. Thats why I was able to do the math. I wanted to know is it possible that memory has a part to play in cutting it off?